# How to change ID name in chrome and save it permanently?

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector, power-automate-desktop

I got a web form to enter 5000 contact numbers.
I'm trying to input data automatically through Power Automate.

But then that doesn't work properly. Because the ID name of two field are the same in the form. as a result same data are copied in both field. Is there any solution from power automation software? or is there any way to change the HTML ID from the browser and save it permanently in that browser?

Please help me.
And please note I've no access to the particular website to change from the server site.
[image]

Comment: Power Automate and Power Automate Desktop are not the same thing.  Is this Power Automate **Desktop**?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes it's Power Automate Desktop. I solve ID related issue with Page Manipulator extension. Now it puts different data in different field. But here I'm facing another issue. When i fill data through Power Automate Desktop, form do not accept the data. It acts like blank field submission. But when I copy same data manually, it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Jquery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) to identify UI elements. Use something like below in the Text editor of your UI element:

```
label:contains("Retailer Number")
```

[image]

Tomasz Poszytek also has a video about his:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lpk35MeTgFA&t=1704s

Comment: Thank you brother for sharing that amazing idea and tutorial. I tried as you said, but UI Element Selector doesn't select field of that particular website. But it works on other website.